# Getting redirected to router page

Tags: linux, networking

I have recently installed Manjaro on an old Dell Vostro 1014 laptop. Whenever I connect to the wifi it keeps redirecting to the router home page (192.168.1.1).

If I try pinging `www.google.com` I get a strange result,

```
ping www.google.com
64 bytes from _gateway(192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=1 ttl = 64 time = 2 ms
```

I can use the wifi perfectly on my Macbook Air 2017, my phone, and even on windows. Phone hotspot also works perfectly fine with the laptop ( internet works and ping returns values). The router is an i-Ball 300M MIMO Wireless-N Broadband Router.

I have tried 4 different distros and am facing the same issues with all.

Comment: make/model of laptop please

Comment: Indeed, What _exactly_ does this command return `ping -c3 www.google.com`? Even the error messages will help us start to diagnose the issue

Comment: It's an old, Dell Vostro 1014, the wifi router is an i-Ball 300M MIMO Wireless-N Broadband Router. Okay, now even the home page isn't opening. pinging 192.168.1.1 returns values <1 ms.

Comment: pinging www.google.com, returns  64 bytes from _gateway(192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=1 ttl = 64 time  = 2 ms and similar. Google isn't opening, nor is 192.168.1.1 opening. The browser shows unable to connect in both cases.

Comment: This [AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1262429/436624) may be of some help, but please don't follow it, first we need to know your wlan hw (wireless card) inside the laptop for one thing, and the whole boot `dmesg` output to some https://pastebin.com service probably (you can set some expiry, a week or so), if you don't know how to get it, this might help: `\dmesg --color=never > dmesg.txt 2>&1`

Comment: I forgot to tell you an example of identification of you WLAN card: `lspci -vvvnn | grep -i network -A 10`, please [Edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/658307/edit) your question to fill in the info. Thanks.